# RestContext.request.params.get gives null value for Test Class

Tags: unit-test, parameters, null

RestContext.request.params.get gives null value for Test Class

Following is my code and Debug logs :

APEX CLASS :

```
 String accountRecordId= RestContext.request.params.get('accountRecordId');   
 System.debug('GetSuccessManagerInfo:'+ accountRecordId);
```

TEST CLASS :

```
 reqExp.requestURI = sfdcBaseURL +'/services/apexrest/SM/myMethod?accountRecordId=' + objAcc.id;  
 System.Debug('-------Nilesh-reqExp.requestURI--'+reqExp.requestURI);
```

DEBUG LOGS :

```
USER_DEBUG|[53]|DEBUG|-------Nilesh-reqExp.requestURI--https://yp--DEV.cs15.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/SM/myMethod?accountRecordId=001e000000pURpNAAW

|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|GetSuccessManagerInfo:null
```

Any suggestion or help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually *set* the `RestContext.request` in your test class and then set any params you want through that.

```
RestContext.request = new RestRequest();
RestContext.request.params.put('accountRecordId', accountRecord.Id);
```